# Are they Cylons?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, caprica

In the show *Caprica*, they use several actors who also appeared in *Battlestar Galactica*. *Caprica* is supposed to have taken place at the very beginning of Cylon creation (well before the advent of human-form Cylons). Are they trying to tell us something we didn't know, such as Cylons outside of the '12' or were the creators simply using actors they knew and liked? If the latter is true, it seems a bit tortuous and demonstrates a blatant disregard for fans. They, surely, must have known that endless theories would be presented in an attempt to explain this.

Comment: Just a random speculation, but isn't it possible that when the cylons decided to create humanoid versions, they based their appearance on records of real people? Were the characters who these actors played "important" people in the context of the show's world (leaders, scientists etc.)?

Comment: @Hypnosifl [The Zoe AI was to become the basis of the Number Six Cylons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoe_Graystone), who look nothing like her

Comment: Then that would imply that the 'persons' we see in Galactica are Cylons; which is the point of my question. Otherwise how could 'real' people be walking around on Galactica later.

Comment: Just to clarify, the people in question were misc. people in Caprica who showed up in Galactica without ever being accused or assumed to be Cylons.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood--I thought when you talked about "actors who also appeared in Battlestar Galactic" you meant actors who played cylons on Galactica playing non-cylons on Caprica, but if you actually meant that non-cylons on Galactica also appeared as non-cylons on Caprica, I think this could just be a "Back to the Future III" type scenario where some character's ancestor is played by the same actor as the original character.

Comment: No, I meant the latter. What you refer to as the BTF III scenario, I call misplaced in a show where so much of the shows lore revolves, specifically, around people looking identical. In Back to the Future, there was no basis of clones or anything of the sort so having people look alike was self explanatory. In a show that exist in a universe where we, the viewer, were so inundated in the idea that we needed to look for any likeness between people, to be so suspicious of anyone and everyone; the idea of them using identical actors is, I feel, a little disrespectful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ronald D. Moore [spoke](http://www.denofgeek.com/tv/battlestar-galactica/20401/ronald-d-moore-interview-caprica-battlestar-galactica-virtuality-and-more) about the re-using of actors from BSG in Caprica. Although he doesn't specifically reference human-form cylons, the clear implication is that casting decisions are an out-of-universe decision and that fans shouldn't read any special significance into it.

> **Is the re-using of actors from Battlestar in Caprica, is it a direct reference to ancestry?**
>
> *We're kind of being vague about that. We're not really specifically saying that those are the actual ancestors of the characters they
>   played, but if the audience would like to think that, there's really
>   no reason why they can't.*

Comment: I suspected as much. Considering the time frame, them being secret Cylons is really out of the question. Basically, they liked those actors and he came up with an off the cuff answer to a question regarding the decision. Always the producer and a good one. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Still though, I think it's a little disingenuous to use the same person in a universe where the whole idea is to notice people who look identical.

Comment: Out of 15 titled characters in "Blood and Chrome", 10 of them had already had roles in either BGS or Caprica. 7 had already had roles in both.

Comment: That I hadn't noticed before but It's been a while since I've watched Blood and Chrome. To be frank though, that comes off as lazy to me. The creators are sci-fi fans, they know how we think; could you ever imagine Star Trek using Pat Stewart in Voyager and trying to pass him off as a trans-port chief, for example? Just sayin'...

Comment: Actually, just to clarify that point, a better analogy would be if the Borg hinted in the last episode of TNG that they might have created a Picard clone then in Voyager, Pat Stewart played a role and the creators just said, "It's merely a coincidence, pay no attention."

Comment: @xXGrizZ - They recycled Trek actors like you wouldn't believe. Jeffrey Combs had nine separate characters, including several episodes where he had roles opposite himself.

Comment: @xXGrizZ The actor for Tuvok had previously appeared on TNG as a human - almost no makeup difference (unlike Jeffrey Combs), as did the actor for Tom Paris

Comment: Very good point. Yet, in Star Trek, A major premise of the show's universe didn't revolve around people looking the same.

Comment: @xXGrizZ - Er, that was the premise of at the entire run of DS9

Comment: They are not the only ones to reuse actors. Look at Mike Dopud: he appeared in Stargate SG1, Atlantis and Universe as completely different characters. He is one of those actors that do a large number of minor roles in many programmes. He  even appeared in Caprica (Sal), Blood & Chrome (Deke Tornvald), TRS (Spec. Gage) as completely different characters.

Comment: Just an update: Just happened to watch a BSG Panel from DragonCon 2009 and one of the question's was if (Luciana Carro) could say anything about her being on the show 'Caprica'. She said she couldn't really say anything except that she is NOT a Cylon and she is NOT an ancestor of Kat but could not give any other info regarding the show. So that really throws out any in universe explanation and really only leaves - the creators like certain actors.